# What could “aus” mean in this case?

Tags: preposition, meaning-in-context

> **Aus** ihm wurde ein Spitzensportler.

What does "aus" mean in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me mark this differently:

> **Aus ihm** wurde ein Spitzensportler.

This adverbial using *aus+Dativ* tells the origin. He was the origin, a *Spitzensportler* is the result.

Telling whether location or origin is meant is sometimes tricky:

> **Aus dieser Kaderschmiede** kommen nur Spitzensportler.

Comment: Both fall together in *herauskommen, was kommt dabei heraus* "what will come of it", perhaps akin to *herausarbeiten* "to work out, extract".

Comment: I'd like to remark, that Kaderschmiede can be translated as "elite training facilyty", as I don't think it is a common word among German learners.

Comment: I use such less common compound words by purpose to make people research them. It creates an interest in the language. You could look up the definition in Wikitionary or even Wikipedia in this case. *So why in German, a school for sports people is a blacksmith's shop?*